# How to render text that contains a tooltip / hover state?

Tags: hyperlinks, hover, tooltips

I'm wondering about the best way to represent text that contains a flyout / tooltip (similar to Foursquare - see image below) but is not a link to another page.

[image: Foursquare flyout]

In my case, there are a number of these text links on a given page, so having a tooltip / question-mark icon would clutter up an already clean interface. Should the text be black with a link underneath? What is a good technique for this (below is an example of the text that will contain a flyout)

[image: Black text that requires flyout]

Comment: Do they only display on hover, or on click? If it's only on hover, is there a different action when the link item is clicked?

Comment: only on hover - there is nothing to click to (like another page)

Answer (score 2):

[I've been having this question as well](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20197/is-it-ok-to-style-a-label-as-a-link-to-trick-users-into-hover-it) a few months back. I learned that conventionally popup/tooltip content is cued is by using a dotted underline.

[image]

Comment: This is fine for abbreviations (as shown in your image) but I'm not sure it's ideal for full content areas to display via dotted underline links.

Comment: Ok, I can agree with that. However, if the user understands the cue (something will appear if I hover that object) and then hovers it I don't really see what the problem is. It seams a bit of a waste only having it exclusive for abbreviations, the result is in the end very similar for both cases.